# Select Rows Where Any of Multiple Columns is in Parameter Values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have multiple columns which store unique, distinct identifiers that can be used interchangeably. I would therefore like to select records where either `Col1` or `Col2` is equal to any of a number of supplied parameters. I have tried the following, and variations, IE, where `Col1 in (?, ?)` or `Col2 in (?, ?)`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE EXISTS (Col1, Col2) IN (?, ?);
```

I can currently acheive this using the following, however, it's long and unwieldy, since it repeats `? in (Col1, Col2)` for each query I would like to bind.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ? in (Col1, Col2) OR ? in (Col1, Col2);
```

Ultimately, my query may have up to 1000 parameters (all will be unique), so I was wondering if there is any more natural way to do the above query?

Comment: If your DB were properly normalized, there would be only one `ColX` per row, and you could simply join this table with the search values.

Comment: @CL, this involves external database identifiers for data with lots of rows, of which there are plenty, they are used interchangeably. Some of the identifiers are from from different specifications, some are synonyms, some are from competing groups, but all reference the same thing. For performance critical tasks, I already use a few regexes to identify the ID type and then process queries separately, but when performance isn't an issue, I was wondering if there was a lazy way. A join would not be suitable here. (I understand this is unusual).

Comment: @CL, sorry, lots of columns (and lots of data in the column).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [using full-text-index tables (FTS)](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). You can use the MATCH operator to specify multiple search terms.

```
    SELECT * from Table WHERE (Col1 MATCH 'this OR that OR something') 
                        AND (Col2 MATCH 'this OR that OR something');
```

Comment: This would still require me to rebind the parameters for each column to my understanding, or then use string formatting to insert them into the query.

Comment: Have you considered concatenating the columns? You can put "SELECT ( col1 || col2 ) AS both_cols FROM Table" as a sub query before the MATCH statement.

Comment: Michael, I have, but then that would require wildcard string match. None of the options seem all that optimal, and likely as @CL said, this seems to be an intentional limitation in SQL to avoid bad table design. I think the performant solution, that is, matching each parameter based on the identifier format prior to checking, and then running an independent query for each column might be the best.

FTS is a good approach though after using validating each though.